# How do I pull items from JSON file to HTML code?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm currently having trouble in regards to pulling stuff from a JSON file into my HTML page. So to start, I currently have this code in a JSON file, which is all the items I have (so far) that I want to use for a project to create an online store.

(EDIT: Needed to make this correct as this was originally a Javascript file.)

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "productName": "Chutes and Ladders",
        "image": "../public/ChutesandLadders.jpg",
        "price": 15.75,
        "salePrice": 15.75
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "productName": "Monopoly",
        "image": "../public/Monopoly.jpg",
        "price": 15.25,
        "salePrice": 15.25
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "productName": "Clue",
        "image": "../public/Clue.jpg",
        "price": 20.00,
        "salePrice": 15.20
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "productName": "The Game of Life",
        "image": "../public/GameofLife.jpg",
        "price": 16.00,
        "salePrice": 10.00
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "productName": "TRESomme Shampoo",
        "image": "../public/Tresomme.jpg",
        "price": 45.00,
        "salePrice": 30.00
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "productName": "Michael Kors Purse",
        "image": "../public/MichaelKorsPurse.jpg",
        "price": 145.00,
        "salePrice": 145.00
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "productName": "Apple Watch Ultra",
        "image": "../public/AppleWatch.jpg",
        "price": 200.00,
        "salePrice": 175.00
    }
]
```

Then to show a sample of it, I have this information on my HTML page (index.html) where I want to change the data to the data I have from the JSON file.

```
<div class="badge bg-dark text-white position-absolute" style="top: 0.5rem; right: 0.5rem">Sale</div>  
  <img class="card-img-top" width="450" height="200" src="Clue.jpg" alt="..." />         
     <div class="card-body p-4">
        <div class="text-center">
           <h5 class="fw-bolder">Clue</h5>
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-center small text-warning mb-2">
                 <div class="bi-star-fill"></div>
                    <div class="bi-star-fill"></div>
                    <div class="bi-star-fill"></div>
                    <div class="bi-star-fill"></div>
                    <div class="bi-star-fill"></div>
                 </div>
              <span class="text-muted text-decoration-line-through">$20.00</span>
              $15.20
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer p-4 pt-0 border-top-0 bg-transparent">
           <div class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-outline-dark mt-auto" href="#">Add to cart</a></div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Is there a way to import JSON data into an HTML file, where I can actually do this?

Comment: The item I would like to pull from here would be the one with ID 3. If anyone wants me to edit to show the full HTML code, just let me know.

Comment: You can just do an ajax call like a fetch to do that. `fetch('./data.json')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((json) => console.log(json));` or some such  - that assumes it is on the same site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the steps you might take.

1. Make sure your JSON is [`imported`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)/[`fetched`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) etc, and parsed.
2. Either:

   a) [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) the object using the value of its `productName` property, create some HTML for that one object, and append it to the page, or

   b) [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the array and for each object create some HTML. `map` returns an array so you would [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) it up, and then append that HTML string to the page.
3. To create the HTML the easiest method, since you already have the markup you want, is to add that within a [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), and apply the object properties you want displayed at the appropriate places within.
4. Use [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) to add the HTML to the page.
5. Creating properly formatted currency strings can be achieved with [`Intl.NumberFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat).

Below is an example on how to build the HTML for one object ("Clue"), and append it to the page. All the CSS is missing (obviously) but I did add one line to show the "line-through" for the non-sale price.

```js
const data=[{id:1,productName:"Chutes and Ladders",image:"../public/ChutesandLadders.jpg",price:15.75,salePrice:15.75},{id:2,productName:"Monopoly",image:"../public/Monopoly.jpg",price:15.25,salePrice:15.25},{id:3,productName:"Clue",image:"../public/Clue.jpg",price:20,salePrice:15.2},{id:4,productName:"The Game of Life",image:"../public/GameofLife.jpg",price:16,salePrice:10},{id:5,productName:"TRESomme Shampoo",image:"../public/Tresomme.jpg",price:45,salePrice:30},{id:6,productName:"Michael Kors Purse",image:"../public/MichaelKorsPurse.jpg",price:145,salePrice:145},{id:7,productName:"Apple Watch Ultra",image:"../public/AppleWatch.jpg",price:200,salePrice:175}];

// A function that accepts the array of data, a property
// name, and a query value, and returns the object that matches
// that condition
function finder(data, prop, query) {
  return data.find(obj => obj[prop] === query);
}

// A function to create properly a formatted
// currency string - pass in a number, a locale
// (e.g. 'en-GB'), and a currency type
function toCurrency(number, locale, type) {
  return new Intl.NumberFormat(locale, {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: type }
  ).format(number);
}

// Find the "Clue" object
const clue = finder(data, 'productName', 'Clue');

// Create the HTML using the object property values
// from the "Clue" object
const html = `
  <div class="badge bg-dark text-white position-absolute" style="top: 0.5rem; right: 0.5rem">Sale</div>  
  <img class="card-img-top" width="450" height="200" src="${clue.image}" alt="..." />         
     <div class="card-body p-4">
        <div class="text-center">
           <h5 class="fw-bolder">${clue.productName}</h5>
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-center small text-warning mb-2">
                 <div class="bi-star-fill"></div>
                    <div class="bi-star-fill"></div>
                    <div class="bi-star-fill"></div>
                    <div class="bi-star-fill"></div>
                    <div class="bi-star-fill"></div>
                 </div>
              <span class="text-muted text-decoration-line-through">${toCurrency(clue.price, 'en-GB', 'GBP')}</span>
              ${toCurrency(clue.salePrice, 'en-GB', 'GBP')}
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer p-4 pt-0 border-top-0 bg-transparent">
           <div class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-outline-dark mt-auto" href="#">Add to cart</a></div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
`;

// Append the HTML to the page
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
```

```css
.text-decoration-line-through { text-decoration: line-through; }
```

Comment: Would this be a separate JS file where this information is put in? The css I got it from is css/styles.css.

Comment: Sure. Just add it to a [`script`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) element. Add it to just before the `</body>` element to ensure the DOM has loaded.

Comment: So this whole thing you put in is just a script basically? If it is a script, should I just put this in my HTML file?

Comment: Okay it looks like this part of it actually works. But I need to add all the styling, because I put it on my HTML page. The problem is the image is not resizing as well along with the styling.

Comment: You should get everything sorted for this question as much as you can, and if the image sizing is still a problem, ask a new question @joeyipod. Just make sure you create a [mcve] of the code/markup/css using the snippet tool `[<>]` which you can find in the question toolbar. There will be people around to help.

Comment: Okay. But I want to say this did answer the question in pulling information from a JSON file into my HTML. Thanks. I'll follow up with another question.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to do this is using the fetch() API.
Just add a script tag in your body

```
<script>
   fetch('data.json')
     .then(function(res){
         return res.json()
     })
     .then(function(data){
          return appendData(data)
      })
    function appendData(data){
        var con=document.getElementById("main-container")
        for(let i=0;i<data.length;i++){
            var d=document.createElement("div")
            d.textContent="Name: "+data[i].productName
            //add the data in whatever html element you want and then append it to the container
            con.appendChild(d);
        }
     }
</script>
```

I hope this helps